# Using sed to print lines between 2 patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Index: <filepath>
===================================================================
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
Index: <filepath>
===================================================================
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
... and so on
```

I need to print the line starting with `Index:` skip the line containing `======` and print all other lines until the next instance of `Index:`

The filepath will be different each time, so I need a command that will match the `Index:` part and print that whole line.

I have been trying to use the sed command but I can't seem to get it to print the lines I want. Is there a way I can do this?

expected output:

```
Index: <filepath>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: From what you are describing you want to print the whole file except the `======` lines. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: not exactly. the file contains the same pattern repeated many times. I want to print the lines I want and echo a few messages between each pattern, so I was planning to put my command in a loop which runs until the end of the file. edited example output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up to this command

```
sed -n '1,/^Index:/{/^Index:/!d;}; /^Index:/{x;/^$/!p;n;n;}; H; ${g;p;};'
```

- It deletes from start till the first `Index:` line
- Then it saves into a holding buffer everything from `Index:` till next `Index:` excluding `=======` line, which is assumed to follow `Index:` immediately
- When `Index:` line is met, it prints the content of the holding buffer if it's not empty
- When the end of the file reached it prints the content of the holding buffer

  ```
  $ cat /tmp/test
  First line
  Index: <filepath>
  ===================================================================
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  Index: <filepath>
  ===================================================================
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>

  $ sed -n '1,/^Index:/{/^Index:/!d;}; /^Index:/{x;/^$/!p;n;n;}; H; ${g;p;};' \
  /tmp/test
  Index: <filepath>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  Index: <filepath>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  <lines to print>
  ```

  But as David mentioned, it can be shorten and then it's just a simple

  ```
  sed '1,/^Index:/{/^Index:/!d;}; /^=/d;' /tmp/test
  ```

which is just the same for lines before the first `Index` and then just removing lines starting with `=`

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to `sed '/^[=]/d' file`? (aside from the `First line`)

Comment: Hey, doing things the long way is how I usually do it `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^Index:/{p=!p} p && !/^====/' file

Index: <filepath>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
<lines to print>
```

**Details:**

- `/^Index:/{p=!p}`: When we find `Index:` at the start set a flag `p` or reset it (toggle effect by using `p=!p`)
- `p && !/^====/` If flag `p` is `1` and we don't have `====` at the start of a record then print the record.

If you want to print next `Index:` line also then use:

```
awk '/^Index:/{if (p) print; p=!p} p && !/^====/' file
```

Comment: could you explain this command? I may need to tweak it in the future so I would like to know what exactly it does.

Comment: is there a way it could run until the start of the next pattern, i.e. the next instance of `Index: `. The pattern is repeated until the end of the file and I need to print out some messages along with each pattern, so I was going to put my command in a loop that runs to eof so that I can print messages with each pattern.

Comment: Can you include a better sample input with expected output in question to make it clear. It is easier to tweak this command but I need to understand the problem.